# Thread-local static variables non initialized when imported from module

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, c++-modules

I have been playing around with C++20 modules a little bit and discovered a bug in the first module I tried to write, where thread-local static local variables in functions were uninitialized (or more accurate initialized to zero) depending on call order.

I have boiled down the problem to a short piece of code in a single primary module interface unit without a implementation file, so please excuse the fact that the code does not make any practical sense, it is only to demonstrate the problem. The code works fine if it is instead included from a header.

The problem code: Test.ixx

```
module;

#include <stdint.h>
#include <random>

export module Test;


export namespace Test {

    __forceinline uint32_t TestFunc0() {
        static thread_local uint32_t test_var = rand();
        return test_var;
    }

    __forceinline uint32_t TestFunc1() {
        static thread_local uint32_t test_var = rand();
        return test_var;
    }

    __forceinline uint32_t TestFunc2() {
        static thread_local uint32_t test_var = rand();
        return test_var;
    }

}
```

Now the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

import Test;

int main()
{
    srand(std::time(nullptr));
    std::cout << Test::TestFunc0() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Test::TestFunc1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Test::TestFunc2() << std::endl;
}
```

The output I would have expected would be:

```
(random number)
(random number)
(random number)
```

But I get:

```
(random number)
0
0
```

If instead of initializing with rand() (or any other function) I initialize with a literal like this:

```
__forceinline uint32_t TestFunc0() {
    static thread_local uint32_t test_var = 10;
    return test_var;
}

__forceinline uint32_t TestFunc1() {
    static thread_local uint32_t test_var = 20;
    return test_var;
}

__forceinline uint32_t TestFunc2() {
    static thread_local uint32_t test_var = 30;
    return test_var;
}
```

I then get:

```
0
0
0
```

Note that the __forceinline can be replaced with inline, it makes no difference, this problem occurs as long as the compiler decides to inline the function, if specified or not.
If __forceinline nor inline keyword is used in these function definitions, then the compiler in this case will decide not to inline and the problem code works as expected again.

Also if the variables were static instead of thread_local static that also fixes the problem.

So if initialized with a function call the thread_local static variable in the first function that is called by main will be initialized, calls to the other TestFuncs that were not called first will stay uninitialized / initialized to zero.
If initialized with a literal all the static thread_locals will be initialized to zero no matter the order.

Also like I mentioned before this only occurs if this is a module, not with a header. I dont think this is a problem to do with multiple translation units either, as Test.asm is practically empty and contains no actual assembly.

I compiled with MSVC with /Ox, but optimization level does not change the behaviour at all. Nor do any other compiler flags I tried.

I think I am missing something very obvious, because this seems too basic to be compiler bug.
Anyone have any ideas why this isnt working as I would expect? I am not used to thread_local storage in C++, is there maybe some special initialization I have to do in this case?

Answer (score 3):

> Note that the __forceinline can be replaced with inline, it makes no difference, this problem occurs as long as the compiler decides to inline the function

Then that's a compiler bug. `inline` for functions should have no visible effects on how that function works. Modules don't change this.

Comment: I have filed a bug report for msvc, if it goes anywhere I will append an update to the thread.